# Trying to run cor function in r

Tags: r

Trying to run cor function which is giving me the listed error

> Warning message: In cor(telco) : the standard deviation is zero

And I am also not able to run scree plot because of it.

```
corrm<- cor(telco)
```

Comment: Can we see some data? `Standard Deviation is 0` sounds like all your values are the same?

Comment: You can't estimate (Pearson) correlation if there is no variation in either variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be like this :

```
 corr(X, Y) = cov(X, Y)/(std.dev(X) * std.dev(Y))
```

So even if the standard deviation of one variable is zero, you know you're going to get warnings.